# How do I create client state pacifically?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

I started my first Rome2 game as the Breton faction. I subdued Britannia except for one region, which is my defensive ally.

When I go to the diplomatic menu, I have the "confederation" option, which seems to be simple assimilation. But no option for State client or satrapi.

Does the ability to creat cleint states depend on your culture? Is confederation the only option for Celtics to subdue pacifically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the more so-called 'Barbaric' cultures, e.g Iceni, Averni ,Suebi only have the ability to become confederations and cannot establish client states, i suppose this is because they are not advanced enough to do so unlike more advanced cultures like Rome, Macedon, Parthia, Selucids etc etc.